# merging two files using perl keeping the copy of original file in other file

Tags: perl, merge

I have to files like A.ini and B.ini ,I want to merge both the files in A.ini

```
examples of files:
A.ini::

a=123
b=xyx
c=434

B.ini contains:
a=abc
m=shank
n=paul

my output in files A.ini should be like

a=123abc
b=xyx
c=434
m=shank
n=paul
```

I want to this merging to be done in perl language and I want to keep the copy of old A.ini file at some other place to use old copy

Comment: Kindly put your effort before posting the problem...

Answer (score 1):

A command line variant:

```
perl -lne '
($a, $b) = split /=/;
$v{$a} = $v{$a} ? $v{$a} . $b : $_;
END {
  print $v{$_} for sort keys %v
}' A.ini B.ini >NEW.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %out;
my $file = 'path/to/A.ini';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "unable to open '$file' for reading: $!";
while(<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my ($key, $val) = split /=/;
    $out{$key} = $val;
}
close $fh;

$file = 'path/to/B.ini';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "unable to open '$file' for reading: $!";
while(<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my ($key, $val) = split /=/;
    if (exists $out{$key}) {
        $out{$key} .= $val;
    } else {
        $out{$key} = $val;
    }
}
close $fh;

$file = 'path/to/A.ini';
open my $fh, '>', $file or die "unable to open '$file' for writing: $!";
foreach(keys %out) {
    print $fh $_,'=',$out{$_},"\n";
}
close $fh;
```

Answer (score 0):

The two files to be merged can be read in a single pass and don't need to be treated as separate source files. That allows the use of `<>` to read all files passed as parameters on the command line.

Keeping a backup copy of `A.ini` is simply a matter of renaming it before writing the merged data to a new file of the same name.

This program appears to do what you need.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file_a = $ARGV[0];

my (@keys, %values);

while (<>) {
  if (/\A\s*(.+?)\s*=\s*(.+?)\s*\z/) {
    push @keys, $1 unless exists $values{$1};
    $values{$1} .= $2;
  }
}

rename $file_a, "$file_a.bak" or die qq(Unable to rename "$file_a": $!);
open my $fh, '>', $file_a or die qq(Unable to open "$file_a" for output: $!);
printf $fh "%s=%s\n", $_, $values{$_} for @keys;
```

**output** (in `A.ini`)

```
a=123abc
b=xyx
c=434
m=shank
n=paul
```

Comment: Not tested... or you would be using $file_a for the read instead of stdin on <>. Why is your regex so complex? Why not just chomp $1 and $2? Also \z should be \Z. The regex will also backtrack a lot because of the . matching, should be [^=]. The output key order is also dependent on the order A and B are fed in, but this is not explicit. In reading the whole of all the files, it is also not resilient against large files for the master. Still, quite compact.

Comment: @PhilH: I have tested my code and I don't understand most of your comments. `<>` reads from `ARGV` as long as `@ARGV` isn't empty, so it works fine; you can't `chomp` `$1` and `$2`, and anyway it would only remove newlines from the end; `\z` *should* be `\z`, not `\Z`; I don't care about backtracking in strings this long; it is clear from the code that the file to be modified is the *first* parameter; and I don't expect GB-sized ini files.